# How can I make a function that acts like jQuery's slideUp(), but for directions other than up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to construct/find a function that shows/hides content in a way similar to jQuery's .slideUp(), .slideDown(), and .slideToggle(), except able to slide in directions other than just up.

Here is where I am starting from:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/styles.css">
  <style>
    .main {
      border: solid 1px black;
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 400px;
      margin-top: -200px;
      width: 600px;
      margin-left: -300px;
    }
    
    .downward-text {
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
      text-orientation: upright;
      margin: 0!important;
    }
    
    .up-links {
      border: solid 1px black;
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top: 42.5%;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: -200px;
      width: 600px;
      margin-left: -300px;
    }
    
    .down-links {
      border: solid 1px black;
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top: 97%;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: -200px;
      width: 600px;
      margin-left: -300px;
    }
    
    .left-links {
      border: solid 1px black;
      position: fixed;
      left: 44%;
      top: 50%;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 400px;
      margin-top: -200px;
      width: 50px;
      margin-left: -300px;
    }
    
    .right-links {
      border: solid 1px black;
      position: fixed;
      left: 90%;
      top: 50%;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 400px;
      margin-top: -200px;
      width: 50px;
      margin-left: -300px;
    }
    
    .a-toggle {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="w-toggle" class="up-links" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
    UP
  </div>
  <div id="s-toggle" class="down-links" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
    DOWN
  </div>
  <div id="a-toggle" class="left-links a-toggle" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div id="d-toggle" class="right-links" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
    RIGHT
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p style="padding: 15px;">The WASD keys should trigger boxes to slide out in their respective directions, but only the W/upward direction responds the way it is intended to.<br><br>The A/left direction triggers a box that slides up and down starting from the middle (as does
      the D/right direction), but ideally it would move from inside of the box outward.<br><br>The S/downward direction triggers the box to float up from below, rather than from above (to mirror the W/upward direction).</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#w-toggle').hide();
      $('#a-toggle').hide();
      $('#s-toggle').hide();
      $('#d-toggle').hide();
      $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '119' || keycode == '87') {
          $('#w-toggle').slideToggle();
          $('#a-toggle').hide();
          $('#s-toggle').hide();
          $('#d-toggle').hide();
        } else if (keycode == '97' || keycode == '65') {
          $('#w-toggle').hide();
          $('#a-toggle').slideToggle();
          $('#s-toggle').hide();
          $('#d-toggle').hide();
        } else if (keycode == '115' || keycode == '83') {
          $('#w-toggle').hide();
          $('#a-toggle').hide();
          $('#s-toggle').slideToggle();
          $('#d-toggle').hide();
        } else if (keycode == '100' || keycode == '68') {
          $('#w-toggle').hide();
          $('#a-toggle').hide();
          $('#s-toggle').hide();
          $('#d-toggle').slideToggle();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

There is a main piece of content, and then the WASD keys are intended to show addition content as if it were coming out from inside of the main content in the direction of the key pressed (W is up, A is left, etc.). It works for 'W' (the content slides up from under the content), but it doesn't work for any of the other directions. 'A' makes content appear already outside of the box and expands it vertically in both directions, while 'S' has content slide up from the bottom of the page rather than sliding down from behind the main content.

Here is my second attempt, where .slideToggle() is kept for the up direction, but I tried to use .animate() to work for the sides.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Bootstrap Practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/styles.css">
        <style>
        .main {
            border: solid 1px black;
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 100;
            height: 400px;
            margin-top: -200px;

            width: 600px;
            margin-left: -300px;
        }
        .downward-text {
            writing-mode: vertical-lr;
            text-orientation: upright;
            margin: 0!important;
        }
        .up-links {
            border: solid 1px black;
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 42.5%;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 100;
            height: 50px;
            margin-top: -200px;

            width: 600px;
            margin-left: -300px;
        }
        .down-links {
            border: solid 1px black;
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 96.5%;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 100;
            height: 50px;
            margin-top: -200px;

            width: 600px;
            margin-left: -300px;
        }
        .left-links {
            border: solid 1px black;
            position: fixed;
            left: 44%;
            top: 50%;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 100;
            height: 400px;
            margin-top: -200px;

            width: 50px;
            margin-left: -300px;
        }
        .right-links {
            border: solid 1px black;
            position: fixed;
            left: 90%;
            top: 50%;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 100;
            height: 400px;
            margin-top: -200px;

            width: 50px;
            margin-left: -300px;
        }
        .a-toggle {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="w-toggle" class="up-links" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
            UP
        </div>
        <div id="s-toggle" class="down-links" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
            DOWN
        </div>
        <div id="a-toggle" class="left-links a-toggle" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
            LEFT
        </div>
        <div id="d-toggle" class="right-links a-toggle" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
            RIGHT
        </div>
        <div class="main"> 
            <p style="padding: 15px;">This one is pretty much the same as the last one, except now when you press A/a, instead of expanding from the middle, it slides from left to right (rather than the intended right to left).</p>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#w-toggle').hide();
            $('#a-toggle').hide();
            $('#s-toggle').hide();
            $('#d-toggle').hide();
            $(document).keypress(function(event) {
                var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if (keycode == '119' || keycode == '87') {
                    $('#w-toggle').slideToggle();
                    $('#a-toggle').hide();
                    $('#s-toggle').hide();
                    $('#d-toggle').hide();
                }
                else if (keycode == '97' || keycode == '65') {
                    $('#w-toggle').hide();
                    $('#a-toggle').animate({width:'toggle'});
                    $('#s-toggle').hide();
                    $('#d-toggle').hide();
                }
                else if (keycode == '115' || keycode == '83'){
                    $('#w-toggle').hide();
                    $('#a-toggle').hide();
                    $('#s-toggle').slideToggle();
                    $('#d-toggle').hide();
                }
                else if (keycode == '100' || keycode == '68') {
                    $('#w-toggle').hide();
                    $('#a-toggle').hide();
                    $('#s-toggle').hide();
                    $('#d-toggle').animate({width:'toggle'});
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With .animate(), the content slides from left to right, so it technically works for the right side, but the left side is sliding in the wrong direction, which can be seen by pressing 'A'.

I haven't figured out how to get things to work in the downward direction at all, but even if I found some other specific function to make it work for the downward direction, these different functions behave differently (in the second link, notice how 'W' slides from under the box, while 'A' first appears as a thin line and then expands). The ideal end-goal would be one function which can be altered slightly to change the direction of the slide. It would be even better if it can slide diagonally in addition to up, down, left, and right.

I'm not exactly sure what the best way to approach this problem would be. Any advice helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is without jQuery.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/styles.css">
  <style>
    .main {
      position: relative; /* make sure the children of this container is related to it */
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border: solid 1px black;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      background-color: white;
      height: 400px;
      margin-top: -200px;
      width: 600px;
      margin-left: -300px;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .up-links,
    .down-links,
    .left-links,
    .right-links {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: solid 1px black;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 600px;
      height: 50px;
      transition: .3s all linear;
    }

    .left-links,
    .right-links {
      width: 398px;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      writing-mode: vertical-rl;
      text-orientation: mixed;
    }
    
    .up-links.move {
      top: -51px;
    }

    .down-links.move {
      bottom: -51px;
    }
    
    .left-links.move {
      left: -37.7%;
    }
    
    .right-links.move {
      right: -37.7%;
    }
    
    .up-links {
      top: 0;
    }

    .down-links {
      bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .left-links {
      left: calc(-37.7% + 50px);
    }

    .right-links {
      right: calc(-37.7% + 50px);
    }
    
    .text-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      background: white;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
      <div id="w-toggle" class="up-links">
        UP
      </div>
      <div id="s-toggle" class="down-links">
        DOWN
      </div>
      <div id="a-toggle" class="left-links">
        LEFT
      </div>
      <div id="d-toggle" class="right-links">
        RIGHT
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <p style="padding: 15px;">The WASD keys should trigger boxes to slide out in their respective directions, but only the W/upward direction responds the way it is intended to.<br><br>The A/left direction triggers a box that slides up and down starting from the middle (as does
        the D/right direction), but ideally it would move from inside of the box outward.<br><br>The S/downward direction triggers the box to float up from below, rather than from above (to mirror the W/upward direction).</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script>
    let wBox = document.getElementById("w-toggle"),
        aBox = document.getElementById("a-toggle"),
        sBox = document.getElementById("s-toggle"),
        dBox = document.getElementById("d-toggle"),
        allBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("[class*=-links]");
    
    // make general function to remove classes called .move
    function boxesRemoveClass() {
      for (box of allBoxes) {
            box.classList.remove("move")
        };
    }

    document.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
      let theKeyCode = event.keyCode;
      // toggle W box
      (theKeyCode == '119' || theKeyCode == '87') ? boxesRemoveClass() & wBox.classList.add("move") : "";
      // toggle A box
      (theKeyCode == '97' || theKeyCode == '65') ? boxesRemoveClass() & aBox.classList.add("move") : "";
      // toggle S box
      (theKeyCode == '115' || theKeyCode == '83') ? boxesRemoveClass() & sBox.classList.add("move") : "";
      // toggle D box
      (theKeyCode == '100' || theKeyCode == '68') ? boxesRemoveClass() & dBox.classList.add("move") : "";
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Please notice these changes

1. I have made some critical and important changes to the HTML structure and CSS
2. I didn't check this approach responsiveness so you better check it if you want it responsive